# How to pass api value to useState as its initial value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have been learning react since a week now and I have come across an issue where I want to pass the value to useState and then use that value as default value for my rating component.
Please see the code below :

```
const Produts = () =>{

const classes = useStyles();

const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([
//the below is an fake api data which needs to be deleted 

    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/7RyHsO4yDXtBv1zUU3mTpHeQ0d5.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
        12,
        878,
        28
        ],
        "id": 299534,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Avengers: Endgame",
        "overview": "After the devastating events of Avengers: Infinity War, the universe is in ruins due to the efforts of the Mad Titan, Thanos. With the help of remaining allies, the Avengers must assemble once more in order to undo Thanos' actions and restore order to the universe once and for all, no matter what consequences may be in store.",
        "popularity": 326.894,
        "poster_path": "/or06FN3Dka5tukK1e9sl16pB3iy.jpg",
        "release_date": "2019-04-24",
        "title": "Avengers: Endgame",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8.3,
        "vote_count": 18957
        },
     
]);
```

//here I am trying to pass the vote_average value to useState as its initial value.

```
 const ratings = (movieData.vote_average);
    const [ratingValue, setRatingValue] = useState(ratings );
```

//finally am returning it using map function in rating component below

```
return (
        <> 
            <div className={classes.main}> 
            {movieData.map((movie) =>{
                 return(
                    <Card className={classes.cardMain} key={movie.id}>
                   <CardActionArea>
                       <CardMedia className = {classes.cardImage}>
                          <img style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}} 
                               src ={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}`} 
                               alt = "movie poster"/>
                       </CardMedia>
                       <CardContent className = {classes.cardContent}>
                           <Typography>  {movie.original_title} </Typography>
                           <Typography 
                                      className = {classes.typography1} 
                                      variant="body2" 
                                      component = "p"
                            > {movie.release_date} 
                            </Typography>
                           <Rating 
                                className = {classes.typography2} 
                                name = "ratings"
                                value = {ratingValue}
*//here am trying to render/return that vote_average value and then change when user clicks or selects*
                       

     onChange = {(event, newRating) => {
                                  setRatingValue(newRating);
                                }}

                           />  
                       </CardContent>
                   </CardActionArea>
                   <CardActions >
                       <Button className = {classes.cardButton} >Watch</Button>
                       <Button className = {classes.cardButton}>Like</Button>
                       <Button className = {classes.cardButton}>Rent</Button>
                   </CardActions>
               </Card>
                 );
                   
            })}
           
            </div>
             
              
        </>
    )
};
export default Produts;
```

can anyone please let me know what can I do and how ??

Thanks a million in advance.

please see I am trying to refer to this documentation using sample component
https://material-ui.com/components/rating/#rating

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. If you need to get the `movieData` from an API, you'll have to do that in a parent component that passes the data down as a prop, or in that component in an `useEffect()` call, so the data gets loaded after the component mounts.

Comment: You cannot pass an API result as initial value if the component itself makes the request. You can either a) use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to set "initial" state and render "loading" or whatever until the API call finishes or b) load the API result in a parent component and only mount the component when the data is available and pass it down as prop

Comment: Hi @AKX I have got the data but I want to change the ratings when user clicks on the Icon button. with on change event? any leads sir ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create separate hooks(useState) for rating because your movieData is an array so you need to change the direct value in the movieData array using useState. You can change in your component like this.

let tempMovieData = {...movieData}; > Spread operator use to copy the object value and asign to variable.

```
<Rating 
  className = {classes.typography2} 
  name = "ratings"
  value ={movieData.vote_average}
  onChange = {(event, newRating) => {
    let tempMovieData = {...movieData};
    tempMovieData.vote_average = newRating;
    setMovieData(tempMovieData);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Hi sedhal, 

I tried your solution but seesm like after I click on rating Icon the error says function not defined and also 28 stack frames were collaps. Can you please help a bit ?

Comment: You need to change the method onChange to onBlur because when you write one word so call the onChnage method many times and the state value is undefined. Can you please upload your code in code sandbox so I can check and try to solve it.
https://codesandbox.io/

Or you can do using update array of object rating values using of an index.

Comment: Hi @sedhalsoni please find the code here as you said I have uploaded the code. 
[https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/Produts.js&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800]
Thanks

Comment: code updated in sandbox. please check and let me know @TapeshPatel

Comment: Hi @sedhal I tried to see the changes but could not find any. Can please share a link if you any or a screenshot so that I can try. Thanks and sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: You can check > https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-https-tivp9?file=/src/Produts.js

Comment: Hi @SedhalSoni Thanks a million for the help. it seems like solution does work for very first item only. that is when I click on the rating icon it is only changing the first Item, even if I try to click anyother Item it only updates first. is there any missing bits sir? also if I divide this {movieData.vote_average} by 2 it breaks it. Thanks for the help and support.